# Dialogue punctuation

Tags: punctuation

What is the right punctuation for this dialog (direct speech) in Italian?

"I am John," he said. "Who are you?"

**"Io sono John", disse. "Tu chi sei?"**

I know I'm supposed to delete the double quotes and use (em or en) dashes instead, but I'm not sure how many of them I need, and where to place them.

Comment: Actually, you are supposed to do whatever your publisher has fixed in its “norme editoriali” or “norme redazionali”, which may envision guillemets («»), inverted commas (“”), en- or em-dashes, or even something else. I have a collection of these *norme*, put together in years of working as a translator, and I'd say that no two of them are equal, also taking into account what to do with punctuation: «“Sono John”**,** disse» vs. «“Sono John” disse» and so on. See [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/69/should-one-prefer-or) for a similar (duplicate?) question.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 3):

The punctuation you wrote is right.

In general in Italian [for direct speech](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/discorso-diretto_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) the following rules apply:

Usually direct speech is introduced by declarative verbs followed by, in the order, colon, a space and a punctuation sign chosen among one of the following:

“...”         inverted commas (or quotation marks)
«...»     angled quotes (or guillemets) 
–...–     dashes

Direct speech statements are enclosed between these diacritical signs.

For example:

> Mi è dispiaciuto che tu non abbia detto: «Accetto volentieri la tua
>   proposta»
>
> – Vado e torno, – disse.

However in contemporary Italian, especially in some particular text types like newspapers articles and literary prose, these signs can be missing or replaced by others.